# Prototyping base classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a strange case where I have to inherit from a class that is defined later in my python file, like the following:

```
class Client(BaseClient):
    def __init__(self, url):
       super().__init__(url)
    ...

...

class BaseClient:
    def __init__(self, url):
    ...
```

I cannot do that because `BaseClient` is not defined when I inherit from it. Is there a way to prototype the base class in the beginning of my code so it works? Or maybe another workaround?

Comment: No, you need to rearrange the file. Also note that you're missing `self`.

Comment: Elephant in the room: *why?!*

Comment: In short, it's because that code is pasted externally and appended to the bottom of the file.

Comment: You could perhaps define `Client` without a superclass, and do `Client.__bases__ = (BaseClient,)` later (works in Python 2.x, don't have 3.x handy to test).

Comment: Well, you should not _paste code externallly and append it to the bottom of the file_. It may seem like a smart idea, but it's just wrong. There must be a better solution.

Comment: I don't like it either, but this is my situation currently.

Comment: @liorblob Could you expand a bit more on what the situation is, how it came about, etc?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to define it inside a function:

```
def get_class():
    class Client(BaseClient):
        def __init__(self, url):
           super().__init__(url)

    return Client

class BaseClient:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

Client = get_class()

c = Client('hello')
print(c.url)
```

Prints:

```
hello
```

Note: Do this only if there isn't any other (more clean) solution. The code could get ugly very fast...

Comment: I hope they don't do it. Or at least never ever ever let anyone else maintain that code.

Comment: @zvone Yeah, you have right, I should add warning in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can give up the inheritance and pull something like this:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, base_client):
       self.base_client = base_client
    ...

def main()
    base_client = BaseClient(url)
    client = Client(base_client)
    client.base_client.do_stuff()
    client.do_other_stuff()

class BaseClient:
    def __init__(self, url):
    ...

main()
```

Comment: ??? `if __name__ in ['__main__', '__builtin__', 'builtins']:`

Comment: Edited for clarity